# Counting an occurrence with for loops and arrays Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Basically i am able to change anything so please let me know.

So i have asked the user to enter a rating inbetween 1 and 10. If it is 1-3 then they have rated bad. if rating 4-7 then good. 8-10 excellent.
What i cant seem to do is pulse 1 onto bad,good,excellent.

Please plug this into Java Eclipse and enter 2 "Bad"(1-3) values. And it displays one. I dont know how to fix it.

Thankyou

HERE IS THE RELEVANT PIECE CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=0;; i++)
    {
        question++;
      Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("What what would you give the food out of 10");
      rating[i]= scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Do you wish to enter another value? Y/N");
      answer[i]=scan.nextLine();
      if(scan.hasNext("N"))
        {
        for (int x = 0; x <=question; x++)
        {           
        if( rating[i] <=3 && rating[i]>=1 ) 
            {
                Bad[i]++;
                }
                else
            if(rating[i]<=6 && rating[i]>=4)
            {
                Good[i]++;
            }
            else
                if(rating[i]<=10 && rating[i]>=7)
                {
                    Excellent[i]++;
                }
```

Comment: First, this doesn't compile, so putting it into Eclipse doesn't help understand what's wrong. Then, where are you displaying anything? What does "pulse 1 onto bad,good,excellent" mean? Also, why are you allocating a new `Scanner` each time through the outer loop? What's the purpose of the inner loop?

Comment: Please show us all of the code so we can help.

Comment: We need to see where and how you instantiate your arrays, which by the way, really should begin with a lowercase letter.